# C++ How to access an SMB NAS file?

Tags: c++, linux

How can I access a file over NAS  (SMB) using c++ on a Linux machine?

On Windows, it is very easy. You just use:

```
ifstream infile("\\\\SERVER\FOLDER\file.txt", ifstream::binary);`
```

On Linux, this does not work!

Answer (score 2):

You need to mount it and then you can access it like the same way. Have a quick look at this:

http://www.linuxnix.com/2009/09/8-ways-to-mount-smbfs-samba-file-system-in-linux.html

Once mounted it becomes available at whatever path you mounted it to.

Answer (score 1):

You either mount your share, or use an SMB client library.

If you mount a share, all files pm it are available as local files (and the path separator will be / and not \). Help on mounting SMB  shares is off topic here though. Try http://superuser.stackexchange.com.

Using a library is on topic. You can use libsmbclient which is a part of Samba distribution. It is easy to use as it resembles stdio.h API. You will need to supply user's Windows credentials to libsmbclient if your shares require them. You will need to ask for passwords securely, or use Kerberos authentication which is a separate big topic.